# Getting SEHException when trying to create a Discord DM

Tags: .net, discord, discord.net

I have a Discord bot that I wrote in vb.net to message users after they initially join my server. In testing I've had no issues with it at all. I've triggered it as the owner with a command and I've triggered it with a family member's account that I had join the server.

However in the first time that a real user joined since turning on the bot, I got an exception when trying to create the DM conversation that I've never received before.

The relevant code is:

```
Dim conversations As New Dictionary(Of ULong, Dictionary(Of String, String))
Private Function HandleUserJoined(user As SocketGuildUser) Handles client.UserJoined
    conversations.Add(user.Id, New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"guild", user.Guild.Id}, {"awaiting", "name"}, {"discordid", user.Id}})
    user.SendMessageAsync($"Hello, {user.Nickname}! Welcome to the Neighborhood Discord Server!")
End Function
```

And the first few lines of the error report (there are 85): (note line 112 is conversations.add, but the error suggests the problem is in "GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync")

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketUser.<GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketUser.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync(RequestOptions options)
   at Discord.UserExtensions.<SendMessageAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Discord.UserExtensions.SendMessageAsync(IUser user, String text, Boolean isTTS, Embed embed, RequestOptions options)
   at SWNABot.Module1.HandleUserJoined(SocketGuildUser user) in C:\Users\ssher\source\repos\SWNABot\Module1.vb:line 112
   at SWNABot.Module1._Closure$__._Lambda$__R9-1(SocketGuildUser a0)
   at Discord.EventExtensions.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
```

What's causing this error?

Comment: While that specific error in unfamiliar. It should be noted that an error is thrown if a user had their DMs disabled.

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing. What does it mean for a user's DMs to be disabled and is there a way to check for that?

Comment: It's a privacy setting. Enable/Disable direct messages from server members. If it's disabled, a user in the server needs to be your friend in order to send you a message. Since bots can't have friends it essentially blocks bots from sending you messages. There is no way to check for it, you essentially wrap the send message in a try/catch